# Using cout << endl; between functions fixes code

Tags: c++

I have simplified the code to get rid of unrelated objects. This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

fstream asdf;
int input;


void import_image(){
    asdf.seekg(0);
    char character;
    for(int k = 0; k < 40; k++){
        asdf.get(character);
        input = (unsigned int)(unsigned char)character;
    }
}

void print_hello_world(){
    for(int rows; rows <= 27; rows++){
        cout << "hello world" << endl;  
    }
    cout << "goodbye.";
}


int main(){
    asdf.open("abc.txt", ios::binary | ios::in);
    cout << asdf.is_open() << endl;
    
    import_image();
    //cout << endl;
    print_hello_world();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Running this code results only in

```
    1
    goodbye.
    --------------------------------
    Process exited after 0.1511 seconds with return value 0
```

however removing double slash (simply adding `cout << endl;`) fixes everything. I have no idea why it happens and would like to now why is it so. I know that variable "rows" has no value, but why does printing a new line fix everything?

Comment: `rows` in `for(int rows; rows <= 27; rows++){` is used without being initialized. Initialize to proper value.

Comment: As already said `rows` is not initialized, which results in undefined behavior. Adding `cout << endl;` results in making the code seemingly work, but it is still undefined behavior.

Comment: Seen this error so often recently `for(int rows;` but never saw it previously. Does everyone copy from the same bad code?

Comment: Any time you get in the situation that the title mentions expect that your code has undefined behavior.

Comment: I think the modern OS security feature of preventing information leakage by zeroing memory pages before giving them to a new process confuses new users to believe that the compiler is initializing some variables to 0 when its not. They try some code in main() and it appears to zero memory but that is not what is really happening. And they don't understand why it breaks when calling it in a function or when adding more code to main

Comment: if your compiler didn't warn about this you have to tweak your warning level, if it did, read warnings and take them serious

Comment: or even better treat warnings as errors (gcc `-Werror`). because unless you understand a warning thats how it should be treated

Comment: @idclev463035818 `-Werror` still needs activated warnings, though, but good point.

Answer (score 3):

> The new "endl"
> is a great sign
> that what you see,
> is called "UB".

Your program has [Undefined Behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) (UB) because your `int rows` that you use for the loop iterations is uninitialized.

By UB definition anything may happen. Activate all (sane) compiler warnings to find errors like this earlier in your development process.

Undefined behavior yield working programs by completely random changes (for example the addition of `std::endl`) but in the end it's undefined behavior.